# Creating a select input element HTML for CloudWatch Dashboard Custom Widget

Tags: python, html, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to set up a CloudWatch Dashboard that will call a lambda function and pass it a AWS region name as a parameter.  I would like to allow the user to select the region from a plain old pulldown menu but I can't figure out how to do that so I have resorted to using buttons.  So I have a custom widget that looks like this:

[image]

And here is the lambda function that produces that:

```
import json
import boto3

call_lambda_arn = 'arn:aws:lambda:us-west-1:XXXXXX:function:customWidget_xxxxxx'

def get_all_regions():
    ROWS=5
    COLS=4
    ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')
    table_html = f"""
    <table>
    <tr><th span='4'>Regions</th></tr>
    """
    # Retrieves all regions/endpoints that work with EC2
    response = ec2.describe_regions()
    region_dicts = response.get('Regions')
    for i, region_dict in enumerate(region_dicts):
        td_html = ""
        region_name = region_dict.get('RegionName')
        if i % 4 == 0:
            td_html += f'''<tr><td>
            <a class="btn btn-primary">{region_name}</a>
            <cwdb-action action="call" endpoint="{call_lambda_arn}"> 
            {{ "region_name": {region_name}" }}
            </cwdb-action></td>
            '''
        elif i % 4 == 3:
            td_html += f'''<td>
            <a class="btn btn-primary">{region_name}</a>
            <cwdb-action action="call" endpoint="{call_lambda_arn}"> 
            {{ "region_name": {region_name}" }}
            </cwdb-action></td></tr>
            '''
        else:
            td_html += f'''<td>
            <a class="btn btn-primary">{region_name}</a>
            <cwdb-action action="call" endpoint="{call_lambda_arn}"> 
            {{ "region_name": {region_name}" }}
            </cwdb-action></td>
            '''
        table_html += td_html
    table_html += "</table>"
    return table_html

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    return get_all_regions()
```

How can I achieve the same, but with a pulldown menu instead of a bunch of buttons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cwdb-action` passes a context object to the lambda and this object will contain all form field values from the widget (see what the whole context object looks like [here](https://github.com/aws-samples/cloudwatch-custom-widgets-samples#is-the-custom-widget-passed-any-information-by-default)).

So you could construct your html to have the list of regions in a form, like this for example:

```
<form>
<label for="region">Select a region:</label> 
<br />
<select id="region" name="region">
    <option value="us-east-1">us-east-1</option>
    <option value="us-west-2">us-west-2</option>
    <option value="eu-west-1">eu-west-1</option>
    <option value="sa-east-1">sa-east-1</option>
</select>
</form>

<br />

<a class="btn">Execute</a>
<cwdb-action action="call" endpoint="LAMBDA_ARN" />
```

Then you can get the region value from the event like this:

```
event["widgetContext"]["forms"]["all"]["region"]
```